# How to change scaladoc default ordering to "by inheritance"?

Tags: scala, sbt, scaladoc

I generate scaladoc by using the sbt command `doc`. The generated scaladoc has default ordering set to `Alphabetic`. I can manually change it to `By inheritance`, but when I visit another class documentation, the ordering reverts back to `alphabetic`.

Is there a way to generate scaladoc with default ordering set to `By inheritanace`?

Answer (score 1):

At present there is no way to generate scaladoc with default ordering set to By Inheritance.

The [page template](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/page/Template.scala#L88) hard codes the initial value and switching is handled by some jQuery  [event listeners](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/template.js#L91).

It should be possible to write a simple script and attach it with [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey) or similar that will run the equivalent to click() for you.